# Верстка, css. Артефакты при масштабировании

Tags: масштабирование, вёрстка, css

Всем привет. Возникла такая проблема. При изменении масштаба в хроме (зажать Ctrl и крутить колесико) в верстке возникают артефакты, в виде 1 лишнего пикселя, или же наоборот, обрезание дивов на пиксель где - нибудь сбоку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с этим можно бороться? А если нельзя, то как объяснить появление этих пикселей.

Адрес сайта для наглядности сброшу, если будет нужен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На все воля браузера. Происходит естественно в результате округлений при расчетах масштабирования. Для примера 955 px как уменьшить в 2 раза? 955/2=477,5. Как отобразить полпикселя? Естественно округлив до целого числа, 478. Вот и весь секрет.

Comment: А бороться с этим можно как - нибудь? Ест варианты?

Comment: Я не задумывался о таком. Не могу ответить.

Comment: Сбросьте адрес сайта.

Comment: С конкретно этой проблемой разобрался, банальным уменьшением и увеличением конкретных марджинов и пэддингов. Решения для общих случаев не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Про артефакты при масштабировании почитайте [здесь](http://clubs.ya.ru/ui/replies.xml?item_no=142).